# How to add webpartzone in sharepoint 2010 programmatically on C#?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a really simple question and probably hard answer.
How to add webpartzone into my sharepoint page using C# code?
What I did is: I create visual web part project and added this code to page_init event of it:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebPartZone webPartZone1 = new WebPartZone();
    webPartZone1.AllowLayoutChange = true;
    webPartZone1.EmptyZoneText = "No Data are provided";
    webPartZone1.Enabled = true;
    webPartZone1.HeaderText = "My Custom Zone";
    webPartZone1.Visible = true;

    this.Page.Controls.Add(webPartZone1);
}
```

and it's doesn't work. but can give you some idea of what I want. I'm really confused.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think web parts cannot contain web parts, so try adding the zone into master page dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, what you're trying is a bit wrong, you're trying to add a web part zone in a web part. I don't know if it is possible but you can try to create it via code to a master page.

I mean, you will not add the created web part zone control in "this.page" but to its master.